# Where is pip config file on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS?

Tags: configuration, find, locate

I have searched everywhere and I can not find the config file on Ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS with only pip3 installed
do I have to make one?
The below commands return null:

```
locate pip.conf
```

or

```
locate pip3.conf
```

or

```
find pip3.conf
```

returns

```
find: ‘pip3.conf’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Updated : Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The default locations are ...

```
$HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf
/etc/pip.conf
```

Beware that there was a bug in [pip 20.0](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1914239) (used in Ubuntu 20.04) and fixed in pip 21.0 where it ignored the global and used

```
/etc/xdg/pip/pip.conf
```

---

```
locate pip.conf
```

only works after a `sudo updatedb` was performed since you installed it (happens automatically at a given interval but it is not real time).

---

If there is no default you can create it with ...

```
export PIP_CONFIG_FILE=/dir/to/pip.conf
```

or by just creating

```
~/.config/pip/pip.conf
```

See the [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#configuration) for more information.

Comment: I think you mean "updatedb" because "sudo locatedb" returns " locatedb: command not found", at any rate I did the update and still came back null. and "/etc$ ls -a |grep pip" returns null. this returns null as well"/etc/xdg$ ls -a|grep pip" returns null. I only have Pip3 insalled

Comment: well spotted Max !

Answer (score 3):

You can run the following command which will give you the location of the different files:

```
pip config -v list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip config -v list
```

works like a charm, it'll list all the conf locations where it could be